# mail function not working with google captcha

Tags: php, jquery

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
       <form method="post" action="" name="contactForm" id="contactform" class="clearfix">
        <fieldset>
         <div class="float-left">
          <div class="coolfx fadeInUp">
           <!--<span>*Name<label for="name"></label></span>-->
           <span><input type="text" id="contactName" name="name" placeholder="*Name" class="text" required></span>
          </div>

          <div class="coolfx fadeInUp" >
           <!--<span>*Email<label for="email"></label></span>-->
           <span><input type="email" id="contactEmail" name="email" placeholder="*Email" class="email" required></span>
          </div>

          <div class="coolfx fadeInUp">
           <!--<span>Phone<label for="phone"></label></span>-->
           <span><input type="text" id="contactPhone" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone" class="text" required></span>
          </div>
         </div>

         <div class="float-right">
          <div class="contactform message coolfx fadeInUp">
           <!--<span>Message<label for="message"></label></span>-->
           <span><textarea id="contactMessage" placeholder="*Message" name="message" class="textarea" required></textarea></span>
          </div>
         </div>
        </fieldset>
            <div class="float-right"><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfsPBgTAAAAAPDkaI1HeSyDm_ecF0iihVsFYBKh"></div></div>
        <div class="coolfx fadeInUp">
          <input name="send" type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Send Email">
        </div>
```

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
      $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
   $privatekey = "******************************";// hide for security
     $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 $data = json_decode($response);


 if (isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true) {?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#contactform .submit").click(function() {
    var data = {
name: $("#contactName").val(),
email: $("#contactEmail").val(),
 phone: $("#contactPhone").val(),
message: $("#contactMessage").val()
 };
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "email.php",
   data: data,
     success: function(){
    $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
      }
   });
   });
  });
</script>


  <?php  }else {
          echo"this is spam"
    }?>
```

I am new in j query how to use j query code inside the php code and also how to verify google captcha code  before submit a mail function nothing working .

before google captcha working my code properly but now nothing working.

thanks

Comment: Please format your code so we can make sense of what is going on.

Comment: i want to check here only if captcha is working then send the information to mail page

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the Captcha inside email.php. Before getting other posted field values you can check for Capcha response. Also don't forget that you need to post the captcha field (g-recaptcha-response) value like you post name, phone, email and messsage.

Comment: i want to check here only if captcha is working then send the information to mail page

Comment: Do you have another form for submitting captcha to the page you pasted codes in your question?

Comment: Not gonna work this way, You need to check it in the server email.php. As I see your code, for first time page load you will not have the JQuery script and when you submit your page then the script will exist but for JQuery script it is a new fresh page load not submit